# Using variables in the mount ntfs-3g command

Tags: linux, unix, mount, redhat-enterprise-linux, ntfs-3g

When I'm not using variables, this works:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdc1 /mydirectory/tools
```

When I wan to put the partition name and a directory path name in the variable:

```
diskName="/dev/sdc1"
pathName="/mydirectory/tools"

sudo mount -t ntfs-3g $diskName $pathName
```

It produces the error:

```
mount: can't find /mydirectory/tools in /etc/fstab
```

What am I doing wrong? What should I do to be able to put the disk name and a directory path in a variable and use it with mount command?

Comment: no idea, try to add sudo echo $diskName before mount call, possibly it's due using sudo but I doubt honestly